# Javascript bookmarklet click button and wait to page load to perform another action

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I want to make a bookmarklet that click a button to submit a form and after that, wait until the page loads and do another function

I use this code and click de button correctly and load the new page:

```
document.FORMNAME.submit()
```

But if I put some code after that, it is executed before load the new page.

Is there any way to execute code through this bookmarklet after load new page?

PD: The scenario is like this: http://allmyvideos.net/jsdm7w3xujae

I want to click the continue button, and when the video load, get the document.body.innerhtml

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I have answered a similar question to this before. Browse my answer history. If you find it and it is useful, give an upvote to it.

Comment: The boomarklet executes in the current website's context. Submitting a form requests a new website where your code isn't present anymore. Depending on your use case, maybe a user script (e.g. greasemonkey) or a browser addon is the right choice.